Sub-optimal execution plan following modification of random_page_cost
Following problems we had with some requests that never ended, we set random_page_cost at 1.2, following general best practices for SSDs.
I now come across a side effect which is the opposite case:
mdm=> set random_page_cost =3;
SET
mdm=> explain SELECT
    count (1)
FROM
    gd_coordonnee gc
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        (1)
    FROM
        gd_associe_interlo_coord_red gaicr
    WHERE
        gaicr.f_coordonnee = gc.coordonnee_id );
                                                               QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=7594528.62..7594528.63 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=7594528.41..7594528.62 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=7593528.41..7593528.42 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Hash Anti Join  (cost=6542818.61..7572026.27 rows=8600856 width=0)
                     Hash Cond: (gc.coordonnee_id = gaicr.f_coordonnee)
                     ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using pkgd_coordonnee on gd_coordonnee gc  (cost=0.44..667580.93 rows=8662897 width=6)
                     ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=5855503.30..5855503.30 rows=41893430 width=6)
                           ->  Parallel Seq Scan on gd_associe_interlo_coord_red gaicr  (cost=0.00..5855503.30 rows=41893430 width=6)
(9 lignes)

mdm=> set random_page_cost = 1.2;
SET
mdm=> explain SELECT
    count (1)
FROM
    gd_coordonnee gc
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        (1)
    FROM
        gd_associe_interlo_coord_red gaicr
    WHERE
        gaicr.f_coordonnee = gc.coordonnee_id );
                                                                        QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=6804572.15..6804572.16 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=6804571.93..6804572.14 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=6803571.93..6803571.94 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=1.00..6782069.79 rows=8600856 width=0)
                     ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using pkgd_coordonnee on gd_coordonnee gc  (cost=0.44..382229.04 rows=8662897 width=6)
                     ->  Index Only Scan using fkgd_associe_interlocuteur_re3 on gd_associe_interlo_coord_red gaicr  (cost=0.57..115.26 rows=675 width=6)
                           Index Cond: (f_coordonnee = gc.coordonnee_id)

With random page cost at 1.2 the request does not end is  after almost an hour, with 3 it ends in a few minutes.
The index used in the nested loop which, it seems to me, is a problem is cached at >99% but the column on which it is based is weakly correlated: -0.02...
What is the mechanism here? Why does the planner not take into account the weak correlation and makes a nested loop?
Or am completely wrong ?
PG version is 14.5
Thanks in advance

I don't think I can help you with your problem, but you could provide more info by running explain analyze (instead of just 'explain') on the query that does finish reasonably fast. E.g. to see where rows estimates are way off.
